# Multiple Word Count in SQL

Tags: sql, counting

I have a list of words I need to find in a specific column , "description of what happenned "

this holds anything up to 500 or more characters. I have the script below that does work

However how do I replace the Name column 1.2.3 with the actual name of the word I am looking for with the total next to it.

Just cant get it to display prob something simple.

```
 select GROUPING_ID ( Amoxicillin  ,Atorvastatin ) as Name  ,count(*) as Total  
 from ( select case when [description_of_what_happened] like '%Amoxicillin%' 
 then 1 else 0 end as  Amoxicillin ,        
 case when [description_of_what_happened] like '%Atorvastatin%' 
 then 1 else 0 end as  Atorvastatin
 FROM "NAME OF TABLE"    
 group by grouping sets (() ,(Amoxicillin),(Atorvastatin))  
 having  coalesce (Amoxicillin,1)  != 0 and coalesce (Atorvastatin,1)  != 0     
 order by grouping_id (Amoxicillin,Atorvastatin)
```

row 3 being the total I need row 1 and row 2 to show the name of the product
result as below

```
 Name                 Total
 1                        7
 2                        9
 3                        4112
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use strings instead of flags:

```
select coalesce(Amoxicillin, Atorvastatin, 'Total') as Name, 
      count(*) as Total  
from (select (case when [description_of_what_happened] like '%Amoxicillin%' 
                   then 'Amoxicillin'
              end) as Amoxicillin ,        
             (case when [description_of_what_happened] like '%Atorvastatin%' 
                   then 'Atorvastatin'
              end
              ) as Atorvastatin
from "NAME OF TABLE" 
where Amoxicillin is not null or Atorvastatin is not null
group by grouping sets ((), (Amoxicillin), (Atorvastatin))       
order by name;
```

Note that I also moved the logic in the `having` to the `where`.